# Using a Variable as a Table Name with CONCAT_WS in INSERT > SELECT

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a database that stores readings from various instruments.  By default, a new table is created in the database for each month and the instrument readings are inserted into the table for that month.  As an example, the table for January 2021 is called data_1_2021_01.
The table for February 2021 is called data_1_2021_02.

The following stored procedure creates a table and inserts data for a specific month from that month's table (in the example, data_1_2021_01) and a second table that contains instrument tag information.  The procedure (shown below) returns the results I need as expected:

```
DELIMITER //
    
    CREATE
    
        PROCEDURE db.DATAPREP ()   
    
    BEGIN
    
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db.DATA;
    
    CREATE TABLE db.DATA (
        ts DATETIME,
        tagid INT(11) NOT NULL,
        tagpath VARCHAR(255),
        curvalue FLOAT,
        t_stamp BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
        INDEX (tagid , tagpath)
    );  
    
    INSERT INTO db.DATA (
            ts,
            tagid,
            tagpath,
            curvalue,
            t_stamp) 
    
    SELECT 
            FROM_UNIXTIME(data_1_2021_01.t_stamp/1000), 
            data_1_2021_01.tagid, 
            te.tagpath, 
            Case WHEN data_1_2021_01.FloatValue IS Null then data_1_2021_01.intValue
                else data_1_2021_01.floatvalue END,
            data_1_2021_01.t_stamp
            FROM data_1_2021_01, te
             where data_1_2021_01.tagid=te.id; 
     
    END //
    DELIMITER ;
```

Now I need to automate the process, so the stored procedure can be executed on a monthly basis and pull in the data from the current month's table without manually having to update the table name in the procedure.  I've declared variables to get the table name, but I can't get the INSERT INTO > SELECT to work properly.  If I use a CONCAT_WS to identify the table/column name in the SELECT statement, it tries to store the result as the data value instead of viewing it as the table/column to pull the data value from.  I've tried using PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE, but I can't seem to get that to work, either.  I'm just not familiar enough with how to make this work in MySQL, so any help is greatly appreciated.  Here's the script (minus PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE statements):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE

    PROCEDURE db.DATAPREP ()   

BEGIN

              -- Set this month's table.  
       DECLARE CurrentMthTable varchar(16383);
       
            -- Set the current year.  
       DECLARE CurrentYear char(4); 
        
               -- Set the current month.
       DECLARE CurrentMth varchar(2);
       
               -- GET the year for the current month table (%Y returns year as 4-digit value).
       Set CurrentYear = DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%Y');
 
               -- Get the current month (%m returns month as 2-digit value).
       SET CurrentMth = DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%m');
      
                -- The entire Table name
       Set CurrentMthTable = CONCAT_WS("_", "data_1", CurrentYear, CurrentMth);
 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db.DATA;

    CREATE TABLE db.DATA (
            ts DATETIME,
            tagid INT(11) NOT NULL,
            tagpath VARCHAR(255),
            curvalue FLOAT,
            t_stamp BIGINT(20) NOT NULL
     ); 

INSERT INTO db.DATA (
        ts, 
        tagid, 
        tagpath, 
        curvalue, 
        t_stamp) 

SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME((CONCAT_WS(“”, CurrentMthTable, “.t_stamp”)/1000)),
    CONCAT_WS("", CurrentMthTable, ".tagid"),
    te.tagpath,
    Case WHEN (CONCAT_WS("", CurrentMthTable, ".FloatValue")) IS Null then (CONCAT_WS("", CurrentMthTable, ".intValue")) else (CONCAT_WS("", CurrentMthTable, ".floatvalue")) END, 
    CONCAT_WS("", CurrentMthTable, ".t_stamp") 
        FROM CurrentMthTable, te 
        where (CONCAT_WS("", CurrentMthTable, ".tagid"))=te.id
        )); 
 
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, SQL cannot use substitution variables for the names of schema items like tables, columns, databases, indexes, stored procedures, and the like.  It just can't. This isn't a MYSql limitiation only, it's true for all sorts of SQL database servers.

As you have discovered, you can do what you need by using MySQL ["server side prepared statements."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) This is a way to use string processing to create your SQL statements, then execute them.

If you do this in your stored procedure you need to write SQL string processing code to create the text of your SQL.  Something like this to copy last month's table into this month's, then erase the data?

```sql
    DECLARE stmt VARCHAR(16000);
    SELECT CONCAT_WS("", 
            "CREATE TABLE data_1_",
            DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y_%c'),
            " AS SELECT * FROM data_1_",
            DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y_%c'), ';')
      INTO stmt;
    /* now stmt is CREATE TABLE data_1_2021_2 AS SELECT * FROM data_1_2021_1; */
    PREPARE s1 FROM stmt;
    EXECUTE s1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
    SELECT CONCAT_WS("", 
            "TRUNCATE TABLE data_1_",
            DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y_%c'),';')
      INTO stmt;
    /* now stmt is TRUNCATE TABLE data_1_2021_2;  */
    PREPARE s1 FROM stmt;
    EXECUTE s1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
```

My meta-point: This is hard programming to get right, even for simple stuff. And it's hard enough to read that you'll have trouble reasoning about it when troubleshooting in the future.

And, for what it's worth, you'll be *much* better off using a single table for all your data from all your instruments rather than a table for every month.  Seriously. Accessing records from a single large and properly indexed table puts about the same load on the database server, is simpler to program, and gracefully scales out from months to years to decades.  A table for each month just isn't wise.

Comment: Thank you!  Unfortunately, I have no control over database configuration and the use of multiple tables.  I agree, though.  It would be much easier to deal with a single table.